# OnClickListener in Listview populated with a CursorAdapter

Tags: android, listactivity

I have a list view with 2 buttons on each row.
I am using a cursoradpater to populate the list.

I am also using the view holder pattern on newview() bindview().

My questions are:
where do i put the clicklisteners for the buttons knowing that the action for the button is different from the action of the list item itself?
Do i keep the onListItemClick ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the `onListItemClick`

You can try binding for each of your button an event in the adapter

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
         button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 // Perform action on click
             }
         });
```

but probably this won't work on the list item, so you need a new aproach as is this described in the [button documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html).

However, instead of applying an OnClickListener to the button in your activity, you can assign a method to your button in the XML layout, using the android:onClick attribute. For example:

```
<Button
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/self_destruct"
     android:onClick="selfDestruct" />
```

Now, when a user clicks the button, the Android system calls the activity's selfDestruct(View) method. In order for this to work, the method must be public and accept a View as its only parameter. For example:

```
 public void selfDestruct(View view) {
     // Kabloey
 }
```

The View passed into the method is a reference to the widget that was clicked.

Comment: But this will not give me the position of the item clicked. I mean in which row the button is clicked.

Comment: You can `setTag()` on the button to set the composed id you need. And you will read from the passed view parameter via `getTag()`