# OnClickListener in Listview strange behaviour when click fast 

Tags: listview, position, listener, mirror, recycle

My post refers to this question:  [OnClickListener in Listview populated with a CursorAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223396/onclicklistener-in-listview-populated-with-a-cursoradapter).

**When I click fast and a lot of time on the same button in my ListView, after a moment my app behaves as if I clicked on another row...** It is like if the buttons were activated AFTER their parents were recycled (note that, when I click on the buttons, the content of my list is refreshed).

**There is a weird 'mirror effect' too...**. Let's say the Listview has 12 items and the items 3 to 11 are shown on the screen. if I click (fast) on the button at positon X, after a moment the application behaves as if I clicked on the button positionned at Y with:

- X:03, Y:11
- X:04, Y:10
- X:05, Y:09
- X:06, Y:08
- X:11, Y:03
- X:10, Y:04
- X:09, Y:05
- X:08, Y:06

Any explanation or suggestion?

Comment: An alternative could be this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461134/android-listview-adapter-onclicklistener-issue but it does not explain my bug (I like to understand :)).